# Proving some properties of the localization functor in the stable homotopy category.

Tags: category-theory, localization, model-categories, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

I am trying to understand the paper named " Localization with respect to Certain Periodic Homology Theories"

Here is the part of it I am trying to understand the proof of proposition 1.5 in it.

> [image]

> [image]

But I do not know how to prove proposition 1.5(i) and 1.5(ii). could someone show me the proofs please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an omission in Ravenel's paper: the definition of a localization functor should also include the requirement that $L_E X$ is $E_*$-local. Once you include this, it's not that hard to prove the statements. First prove:

Lemma: if $W \to Z$ is an $E_*$-equivalence between $E_*$-local spectra, then it is an equivalence.

Given this, if we have two candidates for $E_*$-localizations of $X$, say $L_E X$ and $L_E'X$, then by condition (ii) of the definition, we will get maps between $L_E X$ and $L_E' X$, and those maps will be $E_*$-equivalences of $E_*$-local spectra, and hence equivalences. That's 1.5(i).

To get 1.5(ii), we have $\eta_{L_E X}: L_E X \to L_E L_E X$, and this is an $E_*$-equivalence between $E_*$-local objects.

Finally, to prove the lemma, let $A$ be the fiber of $W \to Z$; then $A$ is $E_*$-acyclic, so the map $A \to W$ is zero (by definition of $E_*$-local). So the fiber sequence splits and $Z = W \vee A$, but since $Z$ is also local, there are no nontrivial maps $A \to Z$. Hence $A=0$ and $W = Z$.

Comment: Is not $L_E$ is $E_*$ local stated at the beginning of the definition? or you meant $L_EX$ not just $L_E$?

Comment: $L_E$ is a functor, so it doesn’t really make sense to ask whether it’s local. Ravenel should state that $L_E X$ is local for every $X$. (Look at how Bousfield does it in the paper “The localization of spectra with respect to homology.”)

Comment: Calling something a localization functor doesn’t make it local — you need to spell out the properties you want.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for pointing out to this paper and thank you for the clarification!!

Comment: Is the localization functor an idempotent Monad?

Comment: I don't think that the localization functor is a monadic functor in the sense of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+functor. You can view $L$ as being a functor from the stable homotopy category to itself, in which case there is no adjoint at all, or you can view it as being from the stable homotopy category to the full subcategory of local objects, in which case it has a right adjoint, not a left adjoint. But maybe you should explain what you mean but an "idempotent monad." It might even be suitable for a new question.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent+monad Here is what I meant by idempotent monad ..... I can also post a new question about it.

Comment: What do you mean by just "Equivalence" at the end of the lemma? it is already by the given an $E_*$ equivalence.

Comment: I mean homotopy equivalence.

Comment: So we will show the uniqueness by showing that $L_EX$ and $L_E^{'} X$ are homotopically equivalent? or I am missing sth?

Comment: Ravenel is working in the stable *homotopy* category, and “homotopy equivalence” means “isomorphic” in that category. So that establishes uniqueness.